# Postgresql: can't start service database system was shut down

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, postgresql

I install Postgresql using

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

then I run

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

then I run

```
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

It says

```
Active: active (exited) since ... 1s ago
```

So it looks like the restart command exits immediately.

the `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log` says:

```
2020-08-13 23:58:39.553 MSK [47081] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-08-13 23:58:39.607 MSK [47081] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-08-13 23:58:39.613 MSK [47081] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 47088) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-13 23:58:39.613 MSK [47083] LOG:  shutting down
2020-08-13 23:58:39.888 MSK [47081] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-08-13 23:58:40.246 MSK [47200] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-13 23:58:40.247 MSK [47200] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-08-13 23:58:40.293 MSK [47200] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-13 23:58:40.470 MSK [47201] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-13 23:58:39 MSK
2020-08-13 23:58:40.508 MSK [47200] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

**/etc/init.d/postgresql**:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:     postgresql
# Required-Start:   $local_fs $remote_fs $network $time
# Required-Stop:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $time
# Should-Start:     $syslog
# Should-Stop:      $syslog
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    PostgreSQL RDBMS server
### END INIT INFO

# Setting environment variables for the postmaster here does not work; please
# set them in /etc/postgresql/<version>/<cluster>/environment instead.

[ -r /usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions ] || exit 0

. /usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions

# versions can be specified explicitly
if [ -n "$2" ]; then
    versions="$2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9"
else
    get_versions
fi

case "$1" in
    start|stop|restart|reload)
        if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
            create_socket_directory
        fi
    if [ -z "`pg_lsclusters -h`" ]; then
        log_warning_msg 'No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"'
        exit 0
    fi
    for v in $versions; do
        $1 $v || EXIT=$?
    done
    exit ${EXIT:-0}
        ;;
    status)
    LS=`pg_lsclusters -h`
    # no clusters -> unknown status
    [ -n "$LS" ] || exit 4
    echo "$LS" | awk 'BEGIN {rc=0} {if (match($4, "down")) rc=3; printf ("%s/%s (port %s): %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}; END {exit rc}'
    ;;
    force-reload)
    for v in $versions; do
        reload $v
    done
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status} [version ..]"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

How do I fix it?

**PS**: The problem I'm having is that Postgresql **wont' start**. After the `restart` command its status should be `active (running)` while it is `active (exited)`.

I tried to purge postgresql and run the

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

again and this is the
/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log:

```
2020-08-13 23:53:33.849 MSK [44882] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-13 23:53:33.850 MSK [44882] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-08-13 23:53:33.898 MSK [44882] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-13 23:53:34.042 MSK [44883] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-13 23:53:30 MSK
2020-08-13 23:53:34.092 MSK [44882] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-13 23:56:17.242 MSK [44882] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-08-13 23:56:17.462 MSK [44882] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-08-13 23:56:17.466 MSK [44882] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 44889) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-13 23:56:17.468 MSK [44884] LOG:  shutting down
2020-08-13 23:56:17.750 MSK [44882] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-08-13 23:56:18.153 MSK [47081] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-13 23:56:18.154 MSK [47081] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-08-13 23:56:18.206 MSK [47081] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-13 23:56:18.392 MSK [47082] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-13 23:56:17 MSK
2020-08-13 23:56:18.455 MSK [47081] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-13 23:58:39.553 MSK [47081] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-08-13 23:58:39.607 MSK [47081] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-08-13 23:58:39.613 MSK [47081] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 47088) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-13 23:58:39.613 MSK [47083] LOG:  shutting down
2020-08-13 23:58:39.888 MSK [47081] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-08-13 23:58:40.246 MSK [47200] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-13 23:58:40.247 MSK [47200] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-08-13 23:58:40.293 MSK [47200] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-13 23:58:40.470 MSK [47201] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-13 23:58:39 MSK
2020-08-13 23:58:40.508 MSK [47200] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-14 00:05:28.033 MSK [47200] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-08-14 00:05:28.084 MSK [47200] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-08-14 00:05:28.090 MSK [47200] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 47207) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-14 00:05:28.092 MSK [47202] LOG:  shutting down
2020-08-14 00:05:28.290 MSK [47200] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-08-14 00:05:28.781 MSK [47452] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-14 00:05:28.782 MSK [47452] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-08-14 00:05:28.837 MSK [47452] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-14 00:05:28.990 MSK [47453] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-14 00:05:28 MSK
2020-08-14 00:05:29.031 MSK [47452] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-14 00:15:05.696 MSK [47452] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2020-08-14 00:15:05.747 MSK [47452] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2020-08-14 00:15:05.754 MSK [47452] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 47459) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-14 00:15:05.755 MSK [47454] LOG:  shutting down
2020-08-14 00:15:05.953 MSK [47452] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-08-14 00:15:06.204 MSK [48037] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-14 00:15:06.205 MSK [48037] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-08-14 00:15:06.257 MSK [48037] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-14 00:15:06.452 MSK [48039] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-14 00:15:05 MSK
2020-08-14 00:15:06.503 MSK [48037] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-14 19:00:11.997 MSK [48037] LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
2020-08-14 19:00:12.032 MSK [48037] LOG:  performing immediate shutdown because data directory lock file is invalid
2020-08-14 19:00:12.032 MSK [48037] LOG:  received immediate shutdown request
2020-08-14 19:00:12.032 MSK [48037] LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
2020-08-14 19:00:12.063 MSK [48044] LOG:  could not open temporary statistics file "pg_stat/global.tmp": No such file or directory
2020-08-14 19:00:12.063 MSK [48043] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-08-14 19:00:12.063 MSK [48043] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-08-14 19:00:12.063 MSK [48043] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-08-14 19:00:12.130 MSK [79907] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2020-08-14 19:00:12.130 MSK [79907] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2020-08-14 19:00:12.130 MSK [79907] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2020-08-14 19:00:12.169 MSK [48037] LOG:  database system is shut down
2020-08-14 19:09:25.177 MSK [84877] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2020-08-14 19:09:25.179 MSK [84877] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-08-14 19:09:25.226 MSK [84877] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-08-14 19:09:25.370 MSK [84878] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-08-14 19:09:21 MSK
2020-08-14 19:09:25.410 MSK [84877] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say you purged PostgreSQL, do you mean you did something like `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-12`? Without the `--purge` flag, the database files will not be removed, only the software to manage those files.

The log is indicating something is triggering a [fast shutdown request](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/server-shutdown.html), which (according to the PostgreSQL documentation) only happens if another process sends a SIGINT signal ([numeric value 2](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man7/signal.7.html)). Something is doing this about 2 or 3 minutes after the database is ready to accept connections. So it appears your server does start, but exits really quick... You need to find out what process is doing this. This could be a rogue process, a Cron job, or the systemctl process that is starting PostgreSQL.

If it is the systemctl process (that is starting PostgreSQL) that is killing it, it is because it can not detect that PostgreSQL is sucessfully started. That is probably due to a configuration issue in PostgreSQL or maybe corrupted data. Try increasing the verbosity of logging or try to start the PostgreSQL server manually (`sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`) to see if you can find a clue.

Or, if you are willing to hose all your data, you could uninstall PostgreSQL and then remove any content still present in `/var/lib/postgresql/12` and `/etc/postgresql/12`. Then do an `sudo apt-get install postgresql-12` and you should have a fresh install again.

If it is a roges process or a Cron job or something, you want to find the PID of the process that is signalling the PostgreSQL server, and fix it. To find out what process is signalling PostgreSQL server, you could use killsnoop-bpfcc (`sudo apt-get install bpfcc-tools`). Start it in a terminal, and wait for your PostgreSQL to die again. You should see a line with column SIG being 2. Column TPID is the process that received the signal, and column PID is the process that is being naughty.

Example of this:

1. I start `sleep 100000` in a console.
2. In another console I check it's PID: `ps -Alf | grep sleep`. I find it's 31326.
3. I start `killsnoop-bpfcc` and check for TPID 31326.
4. In yet another console, I kill my sleep command: `kill -SIGINT 31326`.

The result is:

```
TIME      PID    COMM             SIG  TPID   RESULT
20:29:43  9097   bash             2    31326  0
```

So, process 31326 is signalled with SIGINT (2) by process 9097.